# Specific instructions or workaround for SSH to iPhone

Tags: networking, macos, ssh, iphone, openssh

I am trying to ssh to a jailbroken iphone 4 (OS 7.1.2) from a macbook pro (OS 10.11.1) on university wireless network. The laptop and the iphone are sitting on the same desk, and the wifi router (maybe it's a repeater) is directly above me. After reading many different troubleshooting tutorials, I am still unable to make the ssh connection from the macbook to the iphone, or from the iphone to the macbook.

Using the macbook, I am able to ssh to university computing space. I can also ssh from the iphone to the university computing space. I cannot make the connection to the two devices though.

I've tried using the "private" and "public" IPs of the iphone, and no luck. I get one of two replies each time I try. It's either:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.142.164.50 port 22: Connection timed out
```

or

```
ssh: connect to host 10.142.164.50 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

[This tutorial](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/unable-to-ssh-remotely.1693295/) suggests that IP ranges beginning with 10.xxx.xxx.xxx are "private" and non-routable, which makes sense since this is a big campus. However, [this apple webpage](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13759?locale=en_US) specifically uses an IP of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx as an example, which confuses the crap out of me--either apple's own tutorial is giving damning advice or the 10.xxx.xxx.xxx IP range info is incorrect.

I will not likely get permission to do port forwarding. So, am I destined not to have ssh connections, or what am I doing wrong? Is this my user error, or is it completely out of my hands on this wifi network?

I should also note that I pinging either device from the other incurs 100% packet loss. So, they aren't responding to pings. I also know there are several similar questions, but this question specifically deals with university, campus wifi.

Answer (score 0):

The device in the ceiling is probably a WAP. The university network probably isn't configured to allow devices connected to the same WAP to broadcast to each other. Your two devices, being on the same subnet, will need to ARP to get the layer-2 address of the other device. ARP uses broadcast. If you can't broadcast on the same WAP, you can't communicate from one device to the other.

You could set up an ad-hoc Wi-Fi network between the two devices, but then you wouldn't be connected to the university network.